# DRF serializers does not update the choicefield values?

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-3.6

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ReportCreationData
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'connection_name', 'query_json', 'query_name', 'subject', 'mail_body',
          'table', 'connection_id')


class AssignReportsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        report_queryset = ReportCreationData.objects.all()
        choices = [(t.query_name,t.query_name) for t in report_queryset]
        self.fields['query_name'].choices = choices
        super(AssignReportsSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = AssignReportsData
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'report_creation_data_id', 'username', 'email', 'active', 'channel',
                  'query_name', 'condition')

Problem is whenever  ReportSerializer attribute query name is updated then this updated does not populated in choice field of AssignReportsSerializer.
```

What is the best way to populate attribute of one serializer to another?

```
Problem is whenever  ReportSerializer attribute query name is updated then this updated does not populated in choice field of AssignReportsSerializer.
```

What is the best way to populate attribute of one serializer to another
    Problem is whenever  ReportSerializer attribute query name is updated then this updated does not populated in choice field of AssignReportsSerializer.

What is the best way to populate attribute of one serializer to another